# Get a standard BLE HID remote controller paired and with android and make it functional programmatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard, bluetooth-lowenergy, connectivity

As Title, I used following codes tried to get a hid device automatically paired and be able to trigger key events rightaway, but it end up a strange way that system bluetooth setting page says it is "connected" but still I couldn't trigger any key until I get it reconnected using the setting page:

```
bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
```

With leScanCallback below:

```
BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        ArrayList<String> gotDeviceNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> bondedDeviceNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            Log.d("TEST", "Got Device = "+ device.getName());
            switch (device.getBondState()) {
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
                    if(device.getName().startsWith("BLE_DEV")){
                        Log.d("TEST", "Creating bond...");
                        if(device.createBond()){
                        }
                        else {
                            Log.d("TEST", "Create Bond Failed!!");
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("TEST", "BOND_NONE");
                    break;
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING:
                    Log.d("TEST", "BOND_BONDING");
                    break;
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
                    if(device.getName().startsWith("BLE_DEV")&&(bondedDeviceNames.indexOf(device.getName())==-1)){
                        bondedDeviceNames.add(device.getName());

                        new Thread(){
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    ParcelUuid[] Uuids = device.getUuids();
                                    for(ParcelUuid aParcelUuid : Uuids){
                                        Log.d("TEST", aParcelUuid.toString());
                                    }
                                    BluetoothSocket bSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00000011-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                                    bSocket.connect();
//                                  bSocket.getOutputStream().write(0);
//                                  bSocket.close();
                                }
                                catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }.start();
                    }
                    Log.d("TEST", "BOND_BONDED");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

I tried these two but still not getting to it:

```
bSocket.getOutputStream().write(0);
bSocket.close();
```

With no exception caught and the hid device went "connected" on bluetooth setting page but I still can't get the device(a remote controller thing) working properly unless I do the reconnect in system bluetooth setting page. Am I doing something wrong or it's just a android system restriction?

BTW when the socket connection part is not added it just get a "paired" status.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Not yet so far. The problem seems to be caused by the hardware side so we're waiting for HWs' next firmware update.